# Building virtual raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, mosaic, vrt

I have attempted to build a virtual raster in QGIS to avoid working with several smaller mosaics.

That ended up well, and I saved all of these individual files as tiff files.
Now I am trying to save all of these as one large file, but whenever I attempt to VRT, the result only shows up one of the several images.

How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out it had to do with projection. Each mosaic had a different projections, so once they had all been reprojected into the same utm, VRT was created succesfully.